# Active Directory Roaming Profile for Windows 7 User not Redirecting to V2 Folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, roaming-profile, folder-redirection

I've noticed a number of similar questions here on this topic but not quite on the money for the issue I'm seeing.  Here's the details:

Windows 2008 DC, 3 Windows 7 Ultimate x64 clients;
Profiles share created on the DC (\server\Profiles{user account})
GPO for providing folder redirection on the Documents, Favourites and Desktop folders - Grant Exclusive Rights disabled; redirection for each user account points to \server\Profiles{user account}

Originally, all three workstations were in workgroup mode; I used the 3rd party ProfWiz utility to migrate users A and B to the domain and push their data to the share on the server - worked flawlessly. Both can log-on and see, for example, that their Documents folder is mapped to \server\Profiles{user account} in Windows Explorer.

User C, whole other matter. Things are FUBARed for them.  Their profile seems to have become hopelessly tangled and pointing to the wrong place. On log-in they get a basic desktop, not their original one. Their folders appear pointing to the {user account} folder under Profiles and not their {user account}.V2 folder where all their data resides.

When I check their profile on the workstation it shows as Roaming/Roaming. On the DC, their account profile is pointing to \server\Profiles{user account}. Looking at the logs, there isn't anything untoward - just Info messages indicating the operation is correct.

I'm baffled as to why this profile hasn't taken despite having all outward appearances of being correct. Any help gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the only viable solution I found to the problem was to re-create the user's account using a backup of their Documents, Favourites and Desktop folders, first as a local, workgroup machine profile, then re-running the ProfWiz migration tool to join them to the domain and copy over their folders to the file share.

Prior to doing this, I took ownership of their errant folders in the \{server}\Profiles\ share so that they could be re-created. It took a couple of log-on/log-off cycles to get everything to synch back up and working.

So, word to the wise: *Keep a backup of the user's profile before you do the migration and be prepared to wipe the slate clean and restart rather than disentangling a mangled profile migration.* It will take less time - even if it is aggravating.